# Why is this element not affected by my CSS rule?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML and am trying to make the header row of the table bold.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table>tr>th {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>orange</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

It does not work with this rule, but if I use `table tr > th`, it works. Why is that? From my understanding it should work because the `<tr>` is a direkt child of the `<table>` and the `<th>` is a direct child of the `<tr>`. What did I get wrong here?

Comment: Because your browser injects an `tbody` between `table` and `tr`. So you'll need `table > tbody > tr > th`. But it's better to include that `tbody` in the HTML.

Comment: Note that your example doesn't demonstrate the problem because the **default** font weight for a th element is bold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your example doesn't demonstrate the problem because the *default* font weight for a `th` element is `bold`.

---

However, the problem does exist:

A `tr` element cannot be a child element of a `table`.

A `tr` element can be a child element of `thead`, `tbody` or `tfoot` element.

The start and end tags of a `tbody` element may be omitted.

Thus, if you write:

```
 <table><tr>...</tr></table>
```

The `tbody` element is inferred and the DOM is:

```
 <table><tbody><tr>...</tr></tbody></table>
```

The `tr` element is a grandchild of the `table` element, not a child.

```css
table>tr>th {
  color: blue;
}

table>tbody>tr>th {
  color: pink;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Amount</th>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>orange</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you rephrased the "cannot be a child element of `table`" part, as at first glance it is confusing.

Comment: @Zachiah — It's a simple factual statement. I don't understand why you find it confusing. (So I can't rephrase it to make it less confusing to you.)

Comment: Maybe say it as "cannot be a child element of `table` in the DOM", because in it's current state it is unclear if you are referring to the DOM or the psuedo-XML structure of the HTML document I guess. (Not sure if that made any sense but it did to me (: )